# Cakephp routes redirect base path

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying to make an URL like these:
`www.website.com/`,
`www.website.com`
redirect to
`www.website.com/members/login`
through routes.php.
I have this at the moment: `Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'index'));`

How can i setup the route `/` to reach my desired url?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can just replace the line:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'index'));
```

with:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'members', 'action' => 'login'));
```

However, I believe **you don't want to do this**.

Just leave your routes untouched, and set up `AuthComponent` properly:

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    // Pass settings in $components array
    public $components = array(
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginAction' => array(
                'controller' => 'members',
                'action' => 'login',
            ),
        //[...] rest of your Auth options
        )    
    );
```

For further reference, see [Cookbook 2.x: Authentication](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html).

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have AuthComponent somewhere and `'/'` is set as dissallowed.
`$this->Auth->allow('/')` should help.

Comment: Can you please indicate where should i set this rule? Thank you!

Comment: You have to find in your code place where AuthComponent is configured (check AppController.php first) and after disallow section you can place this rule.

Comment: Haven't found it. I presume this is why this rule won't work `Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'users/member_login', 'action' => 'index'));` ?

Comment: May be.  That router rule looks little bit strange. Shouldn't be `Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'member_login'));` ?